# Spring Boot REST - Pull data from Microsoft Dynamics NAV using OData

Tags: spring, rest, odata, navision

I need to pull data from a Microsoft Dynamics NAV based on OData. I tried the NTLM Auth approach, but I always get a "401" or "NEGOTIATE authentication error: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm)" with my new approach.

I have got a VM which runs the NAV instance. On my local machine I have my dev environment running the application which needs to pull data. Both are not in the same windows domain.

This is my code so far (prototyping):

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connPool = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();

connPool.setMaxTotal(200);
connPool.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(200);

RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setTargetPreferredAuthSchemes(Arrays.asList(AuthSchemes.NTLM)).build();

BasicCredentialsProvider b = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
b.setCredentials(org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope.ANY, new NTCredentials("user", "pw", "hostname", "domain"));

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setConnectionManager(connPool).setDefaultCredentialsProvider(b).setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();

HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
context.setCredentialsProvider(b);

String bodyAsString = "";
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://VM10-2018:7048/GLT/OData/Company('GLT')/Bestand3");

try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

    if (response != null) {
        String s = response.toString();
    }

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is it possibility to access data with the username and the webservice access key I could generate for each user? The user has full permission.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What’s your Nav version?

Comment: Hav you checked that `use NTLM` switched on on Nav instance?

Comment: @MakSim Yes. You are right. I just found it out by going through the settings of NAV.